# Acumatica: Unit Base of UOM is read-only?

Tags: acumatica

I am updating non/stock-item because of wrong UOM but some item's Unit Base is read-only. How can I update it?

I want to avoid deleting and adding the item again.

[image: https://imgur.com/KQl7pMY]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic answer is: `Base UOM cannot be changed for the item in use.`

Generally what `in use` means refers to having that Inventory Item used in the transaction detail of a released document.

The validation mechanism are located in the DACs using `PreventEditIfExists` class.

InventoryItem DAC has the generic validation query:

```
public abstract class baseUnit : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
    public class PreventEditIfExists<TSelect> : PreventEditOf<baseUnit>.On<InventoryItemMaintBase>.IfExists<TSelect>
        where TSelect : BqlCommand, new()
    {
        protected override String CreateEditPreventingReason(GetEditPreventingReasonArgs arg, Object firstPreventingEntity, String fieldName, String currentTableName, String foreignTableName)
            => PXMessages.Localize(Messages.BaseUnitCouldNotBeChanged);
    }
}
```

Other DACs use the generic query types `<TSelect>` to validate if the Inventory Item is `in use`.

For example, this is the validation query defined in `INTran` DAC on `INTran.InventoryID` field:

```
public abstract class inventoryID : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
    public class InventoryBaseUnitRule :
        InventoryItem.baseUnit.PreventEditIfExists<
            Select<INTran,
            Where<inventoryID, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>,
                And<released, NotEqual<True>>>>>
    { }
}
```

So if I create a new inventory item, I can change it's `BaseUOM` field because it's not `in use` anywhere. If I then create an inventory receipt for that item and release it, it creates a released `INTran` transaction and thus the `BaseUOM` for that item become `in use` and un-editable.

I believe the reason for this behavior is to preserve statistic accuracy for past transactions without having to cache (duplicate) UOM on every transaction in case the user change it later on. If that's the case then it's a tradeoff between letting the user change anything at anytime and keeping the database size under control for large transactional volume.

The validation is not exclusive to receipt transactions. You can find the validations requests for other DAC by searching Acumatica source code for `baseUnit.PreventEditIfExists` in source code page (SM204570):
[image]

Comment: This explains why you can't change base UOM. To answer the question how can you change it is harder. I guess you can change it directly in the database or by using PXDatabase class which does no validation. That change would be at your own risk because the validation implies it would corrupt data (most likely in a statistic accuracy way, not in a the application is gonna crash way).